# How to specify a generic type as a restriction in a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic class like this:

```
class MyGenericClass<T> { }
```

On the other hand I have an aggregator class that I use to obtain singleton instances of `MyGenericClass` and of derived classes, where each instance is identified by the concrete class type and by the parameter type. That is, `MyGenericClass<int>` is different from `MyGenericClass<string>` and from `MyDerivedGenericClass<int>`; there is one single instance for each of them.

The main member of the aggregator is the `GetInstanceOf` method, which will return the singleton instance of the specified type. The problem is that I want to specify the type as a generic parameter, but I can't find a way to create a restriction of type *"the parameter must be of type MyGenericClass (or derived) with any parameter type"*. In short, I want something like this:

```
T GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : MyGenericClass<> //This does not compile
```

So, what can I do? Is there any way to specify such a restriction?

**EDIT:** The `GetInstanceOf<T>` method indeed returns T, not void.

Comment: I am confused: why is your method *declared* as void returning, but *described* as returning a value?

Comment: You are right, I wrote it wrong. It's corrected now. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to create an interface, and have your generic class implement that.  MyGenericClass<int> and MyGenericClass<string> are considered to be completely different classes by the .NET compiler.

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
void GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : IMyGenericClass
```

You could also use a shared base class:

```
void GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : MyGenericClassBase
```

Finally, you might try to add a second type parameter to your method:

```
void GetInstanceOf<T, U>() where T: MyGenericClassBase<U>
```

(I'm not sure about that last one...  I don't have a compiler handy to check it)

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479859.aspx#fundamentals_topic12

Comment: I finally chose to have the generic class to implement an interface and it worked fine. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4):

```
interface IMyGenericBase { /* ... */ }

class MyGenericClass<T> : IMyGenericBase { /* ... */ }

class MyDerivedGenericClass<T> : MyGenericClass<T> { /* ... */ }

T GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : IMyGenericBase { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Take a step back and solve the real problem, rather than trying to solve some completely unnecessary issue involving constraints. This seems very straightforward:

```
MyGenericClass<T> GetInstanceOfMyGenericClass<T>() 
{ 
    return MyGenericClass<T>.GetSingleton(); 
}
```

You want a `MyGenericClass<int>`, you say  `GetInstanceOfMyGenericClass<int>()`, done. Why mess around with constraints at all if you don't need to?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would likely create an interface, have 'MyGenericClass' implement that interface, and then use the interface in the 'where' of your method signature.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most posts here - providing an interface is typically the best approach.

However, if `MyGenericClass<T>` happens to be a class defined outside of your control, the other option is to do:

```
 void GetInstanceOf<T, U>() where T : MyGenericClass<U>
```

Unfortunately, this requires your caller to provide the generic type of MyGenericClass as well, but it will compile and run correctly if you cannot change "MyGenericClass".